# How to manage clear cache only when the page is loaded the first time Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex-19.2

I built a page with many Popup LOV and and a button to submit the page. I'm looking for a way to manage the clear cache only when the page is loaded, because I added a Process "Before Region" .- Type : Clear Session state. When the application submits the page make a validation about inputs selected.
[image]

I've tryied to use a DA to clear items when Load page only when the server condition on an item is ugual to 0. In the this case the value works, but if I move to another page and come come back, using navigation bar the page will not clear. 
[image]
[image]

I would like to clean all items when I load the page for the first time and not when I submit the values, but I can't find way to manage the cache browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for this question. I Hope, it'll be useful to everybody.

1)Before Region - Set the Run Process execution option on the process to Once Per Session or When Reset.

[image]
[image]

2)Shared Components - Navigation Menu - Include the page number in the Clear Cache properties of the navigation list entries that link to the page.

[image]